# Match string to list of bigrams

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of bigrams. Example:

```
bigrams = [[(text a, text b)], [(text a, text c)]]
```

I have a list of strings:

```
stringList = ['this is a test string containing text a and text b', 'this is a test string containing text a and text c']
```

I'd like to iterate over the list of strings and compare the strings with the list of bigrams. If match, I'll do some processing.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your bigrams list had a slightly strange format - you have a list of lists where each sublist contains a tuple. There is no need for the sublist, it could just be: `[('some','text'), ('text','here')]`.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what did you do? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

You've described the method correctly - iterate over the bigrams and the strings and look for matches:

```py
bigrams = [[('some','text')], [('text','here')]]
stringList = ['there is some text', 'text here, there is']

for b in bigrams:
   for s in stringList:
      if ' '.join(b[0]) in s:
         print(f"found '{' '.join(b[0])}' in '{s}'")
```

If you want to match the bigrams in either order then simply add another `if` statement:

```py
elif ' '.join(b[0][::-1]) in s:
   print(f"found '{' '.join(b[0][::-1])}' in '{s}'")
```